# How to solve this proxy issue in Vue.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

In my parent directory, I have:

- A `client` folder, which contains a Vue app hosted on port 8080. This app primarily features a contact form.
- A `sever` folder, which contains a Node app hosted on port 5000. This app's primary purpose is to send an email with the info gathered from the frontend contact form.

A component on the frontend Vue app calls the backend like so: `axios.post('http://localhost:5000', {...})`. This axios POST request is then handled in the backend index file with, `app.post('/', (req, res) => {})`.

Up to this point, everything works. The app only breaks when I attempt to add a proxy, like so:

1. I create a `vue.config.js` file directly in the client directory, and add the code:

   ```
   module.exports = {
       devServer: {
           proxy: {
               '/': {
                   target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                   ws: true,
                   changeOrigin: true
               }
           }
       }
   };
   ```
2. I update the axios request to: `axios.post('/', {...})`

After I do this, I receive the error, `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/381/hc0dun1b/websocket' failed: Invalid frame header`

Again, my goal is to create a proxy for the http://localhost:5000 axios call. The problem is that it seems to get stuck within port 8080, as evidenced by the error. I have CORS enabled, by the way.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: I think the `sockjs` error may be misleading you. Do you see the axios request you're expecting to see? Is that responding correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy rules are telling it to use websockets for the connection, which is what the error means. You can't do a post on a websocket. From the looks of things, changing your proxy setting to this should fix it,

```
devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:5000'
}
```